# CI Servers for system simulation

Tags: continuous-integration, automated-tests

My group work for a software of simulation for plane. To achieve a faster and easier validation and verification, we decided to introduce continuous integration. But I have no idea which CI servers should we choose.

Our contraintes:

```
   - We need to compile in different machine with different platform( Linux, HP ) in local net and in client's net.
     I mean, we need to call different functions in different machine in distance. Some of them will need a authorise
   - We prefer a CI servers open source
   - The sources are in different languages, C, C++, Java ...
   - Support SVN, CVS, Clearcase
   - Automated tests and reports
   - The tests need different machines working together
```

I've seen teamcity, it seems well, but it's not open source.

Comment: Don't discount TeamCity just because its not open source (for that matter don't discount *any* tool because its not open source) - its very good at what it does.

Comment: Thanks, i've installed TC in my personnal computer(for a little experiences.
What i'm afraid is that the system and the requirements of the avionic computer could be very special, and if it's not Open source, when ever i want to change sth, perhaps it's not possible.
I'll try any way.

Comment: TC is indeed a great tool and fits all your needs. However, as I suggested, you can have a look at Hudson, which is open-source and maybe one of the best CI tool...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) is for you!

Edit to be more precise about your requirements:

- Hudson run on a JVM (standalone service, using Jetty, or on a Tomcat server). Thus, the plateform is not a problem.
- Hudson is open-source.
- Hudson manages Java projects natively, but you can ask him to compile C, C++ or .Net projects.
- Support SVN, CVS natively, and a plugin for Clearcase exist ([here](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/ClearCase+Plugin)).
- Automated tests and reports: You will need to implement them, of course, but Hudson will launch them for you. For Java projects, simply use [Maven](http://apache.maven.org) for that!
- The tests need different machines working together: Hudson can be launched on several machines (one master, several slaves). Each slave can be hosted by any kinf of machine.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Hudson.

We are using Hudson together with SVN (version control) and Selenium RC (functional testing).

Very easy to set up, has tons of modules for integration, and very visible to all members of the team, especially if you're using the [Hudson Build Monitor](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7522) Firefox plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I used Jenkins earlier, but now I prefer only TC due to it is great for a lot of purposes.

- If you need to work with different platforms, it has great opportunity to install a few build agents with OS specified. Also you're able to install so-called Agent Clouds.
- If you need to build your applications per branch — it will be done without any extra-scripting.
- A lot of VCSs are supported.
- Using Maven you're provided to build even Flex applications, even with running automated test (in case of Windows build agent installed).